# Find Userwise Missing Dates

Tags: mysql

These are the two samples of my table. In the Log table there are some data of entry dates of some users and the User table contains all the user information.

Log Table

```
+---------+--------------+   
| user_id | entry_date   |
+---------+--------------+    
|    1    |  16-02-2021  |
|    2    |  16-02-2021  |
|    3    |  13-02-2021  |
|    3    |  14-02-2021  |
|    3    |  15-02-2021  |
|    4    |  13-02-2021  |
|    4    |  16-02-2021  |
+---------+--------------+
```

User Table

```
+----+--------+  
| id | NAME   |
+----+--------+    
| 1  | A      |
| 2  | B      |
| 3  | C      | 
| 4  | D      | 
+----+--------+
```

Now I want to find the missing dates against the users between a date range. for example 10-02-2021 to 20-02-2021.

So the result should look like this,

```
+----+--------+--------------+   
| id | NAME   | missing_date |
+----+--------+--------------+    
| 1  | A      | 13-02-2021   |
| 1  | A      | 14-02-2021   |
| 1  | A      | 15-02-2021   |
| 2  | B      | 13-02-2021   |
| 2  | B      | 14-02-2021   |
| 2  | B      | 15-02-2021   |
| 3  | C      | 16-02-2021   |
| 4  | D      | 14-02-2021   |
| 4  | D      | 15-02-2021   |
+----+--------+--------------+
```

What will be the query for this?

Comment: Where are you stuck at? what is your attempt? Have you at least managed to join the tables?

Comment: i have started with a recursive query to generate dates but i am totally blank on how to join it with these two tables.